# SAS address formatting

Tags: sas

How would I capitalize the first letters, insert only one space between each address and  insert a comma and one space between the variables city/state in SAS

ie:200   Grass GROVE Lane     SF  CA

Comment: Be more specific. Its not clear

Comment: Please show what you've tried and what isn't working per SO guidelines [ask]

Comment: You can look at the COMPBL, CATX and PROPCASE function to get started.

Comment: https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Base_Certification_Resource_Guide.md